# How to assign variables based off key value pair in dictionary

Tags: python, data-structures

To simplify my problem, I have dictionary:

```
dict = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

and what i want is:

```
a = 1 

b = 2

c = 3
```

Except I need to use a for loop to do this, or another quick way because my dictionary has something like 30 unique keys.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want that as output? ```for key in d.keys(): print(f'{key} = {d[key]}')``` or ```for key, item in d.items(): print(f'{key} = {item}')```

Comment: if you're trying to save it to a text file, instead of print add the formatted string to a list. after the loop ends, save list to file line by line

Comment: @smcrowley that would work if I was looking to write to the console, instead I am attempting to assign a variable

Comment: Why do you want ~30 unique variables?  Why can't you use the dictionary that you already have?

Comment: I guess I wanted 30 unique variables so I can have very readable matplotlib plotting code

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `exec` keyword?

```py
for key, item in dict1.items(): exec(f'{key} = {item}')
```

That will basically tell the python interpreter to execute the variable assignments for you with a for loop. 
**NOTE (See juanpa's comment):** This only works on global variables. This does not work on local namespaces following a change in exec's behaviour from python2 to 3.

Of course, this comes with all the caveats of using exec or eval. DO NOT USE THIS ON UNSANITIZED DATA or it may make you vulnerable to injection attacks. Take security very seriously with these keywords.

NOTE: <strike>I do not know what you are trying to achieve?</strike> Just read your comment about matplotlib. I don't use matplotlib and can not help you with that. However, this is extremely unidiomatic and I would normally suggest that you use indexing/iteration on your dictionary to get values.

Comment: This will not work in local namespaces

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you are right. I will add a note for this. However, it should be noted that OPs requirements do not mention any requirement for it to work in local namespaces. Therefore, I believe my answer is still valid.

Comment: This is working within a class, so yes, in my specific use case, it is in a local namespace

Comment: @JonnyMoshiri this would actually work in a class, class namespaces are special. Note, this means the class body. But if you were going to do that, you might as well just do `vars(MyClass).update(my_dict)`

Comment: @JonnyMoshiri Read this for a better understanding. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec